# Points on a line vs real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

How to prove that every point on a x-axis is a (unique) real number and that every real number is a (unique) point on that line?

Also, one another question. How completeness axiom "proves" that there are no "holes" in the x-axis?

I am confused and this gives me mental breakdown. Please help.

Comment: What does it mean for every point on a line to be a real number? This is not true in the normal sense: for example, for the line $y=x$, points on that line are *pairs* $(x,x)$, not real numbers.

Comment: I thought x-axis.

Comment: If you prove statement for 1D line then you sort of proved it for 2D plane.

Comment: Are you talking about a proof from the axioms in geometry? In this case, you should say what axioms you're working from and also you **don't have an $x$-axis** until you somehow define one. The $x$-axis exists in a model of the axioms, and contains a point for every real number by definition: it is defined as the set of points $(0,y)$ where $y \in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be about proving that there is a one-to-one mapping between $\mathbb{R}$ and a line.

Let me start with a question: what is a line for you? This is a highly non obvious question, reading the first few sections of the [Wikipedia entry for line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)) can convince you of this.

Some definitions of a line are based on a linear relation defining them.
It is then obvious that there is such a one-to-one mapping, in fact, so obvious that it seems a tautology, $\mathbb{R}$ and the line can't really be distinguished.

From there, your second question is very straightforward if you have understood that completeness implied that there are no "holes" in $\mathbb{R}$, since if you have a point in the line, then you can get its position along the line represented as a real number, which would be a contradiction if the point was a hole.

Comment: I did not understand that completeness axiom proved that there are no holes in $\mathbb{R}$. What that even means? I am struggle to understand this.

Comment: @Learner It's better then to ask a separate question, focused on this.